# How to format spacing between reference key and reference text in Bibtex?

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

I want to increase the spacing between the reference key and the text in my bibliography as shown in the picture below:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Bibtex.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly related: [Bibliography - Increase horizontal white space after each entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122529/134144)

Comment: Thank you! First I was irritated since the title of the references thread said "horizontal" but it worked for me.

Comment: Would you agree to close your question as a duplicate of the one I linked?

Comment: The title of the linked question is a bit misleading ... I posted the named solution below for users facing the same problem

Comment: I don't understand why the title of the other question is misleading as the space between the key and the text is a horizontal space. However, if makred as a duplicate, your question will serve as a "signpost"  for future visitors having the same (or a similar) question.

Comment: You're right I was wrong. It's not the title that is misleading but the provided image. The user in the linked thread intended to increase vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

To show the answer for all:

As referenced by leandriis another thread showed the following solution:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\leftmargin\labelwidth}{\leftmargin\labelwidth\labelsep=20pt}{}{}
```

The interesting command is `\labelsep=20pt`

Comment: Does not work for me ?